# WooCommerce Subscriptions: /my-account/subscriptions/ how to make titles like "Next payment" or "Status" clickable to sort subscriptions

Tags: sorting, woocommerce, subscription

Is there a way to sort subscriptions in frontend?

I need to sort them by "Status", "Next payment" or by some "Item meta data".

[/my-account/subscriptions/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3xBL.jpg)

Comment: You have to either write sorting query or the more easy way atleast for me is using https://datatables.net/ . You can make any column sorted without much effort. You can have pagination , search etc. Worth to mention that supprots ajax if you have big tables too :)

Comment: There is accounts with more than 5000 subscriptions and they already paginated by PHP function. Maybe datatables.net is good for less than 500 rows.